# Ninject in Xamarin is throwing an error only when tested on a physical device

Tags: c#, xamarin, dependency-injection, ninject

I've been using Ninject with no problem in a shared project between Android and iOS, however, when I connect an iPhone for testing purposes, I get this weird error:

> System.InvalidOperationException Error loading Ninject component
>   IModuleLoader No constructor was available to create an instance of
>   the registered implementation type ModuleLoader.
>
> Suggestions:   1) Ensure that the implementation type has a public
>   constructor.

My code is rather simple:

```
public static Ninject.StandardKernel GetStandardKernel()
{
    //var settings = new Ninject.NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false };
    var kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel(new iOS.Ioc.IOSModule());
    return kernel;
}
```

Comment: Are you using linking in your iOS project?

Comment: I tried with and without linking

Comment: The shared code just method,which code in  `ModuleLoader` class, you can show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enable linker behaviour to link some sdk frameworks only solved the problem

Comment: Thanks Mohamed - I'd set my linker settings to 'Link all assemblies' to rule out a previous problem and forgot to set it back to 'Link SDK assemblies only' - my error has now stopped (Error loading Ninject component IBindingResolver)